# Duplicate date labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, date, matplotlib

I'm having an unusual plotting issue with plotting dates in matplotlib.
This is the simplest test case I've come up with to reproduce the issue

```
t = ['2017-11-12 00:00:00-05:00',
     '2017-11-13 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-14 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-15 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-16 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-17 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-18 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-19 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-20 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-21 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-22 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-23 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-24 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-25 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-26 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-27 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-28 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-29 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-11-30 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-12-01 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-12-02 00:00:00-05:00',
   '2017-12-03 00:00:00-05:00']

#convert to timestamps in the New York timezone
t = pd.to_datetime(t)
t.index = t
t = t.tz_localize('UTC')
t = t.tz_convert('America/New_York')

#plot.
y = np.arange(len(t))
plt.plot(t, y, 'ro-')

#Issue only appears if you zoom out so x tick label format is "YYYY-MM"
plt.xlim(pd.to_datetime("2017-07-15"), pd.to_datetime("2018-01-02"))

#Print tick label text
ticklabels = plt.gca().get_xticklabels()
strings = map(lambda x: x.get_text(), ticklabels)

print(strings)
assert strings[-3] != strings[-2]
```

The x-tick labels chosen on my machine are

```
[u'2017-08', u'2017-09', u'2017-10', u'2017-11', u'2017-11', u'2017-12']
```

with "2017-11" repeated twice. I would expect the last two values to be '2017-12' and '2018-01'. The tick locations are consistent with what I expect, but the labels are not.

The problem only arises if I zoom out far enough that the tick labels are in the format "YYYY-MM" (instead of "YYYY-MM-DD"), and goes away if I remove the line converting the timezone to "America/New_York".

Is this a bug, or is there something in the model of how dates are interpreted that I'm missing?

[image: example figure showing problem]
This is the plot created by the code above. Notice two x-tick labels with the same string value

Comment: `assert strings[-3] != strings[-2]` will always fail because at the point in the code the ticklabels are all empty strings and hence equal.

Comment: Apart I cannot reproduce this; all ticklabels shown on the plot are different from each other, no matter how I zoom.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why they are equal for you. I set the x-axis range to be many months wide. I definitely get six ticks with non empty labels.

Comment: Don't worry about the assertion, this will depend on how to call the code.  If you run it as script, `get_xticklabels()` will result in something like ["", "","",""], which is completely expected and has nothing to do with your issue here. Concerning the issue, as said, for me all labels are different, you need to be lucky to find someone who can reproduce your issue to be able to help.

Comment: Are you saying that when you run code you don't see any x-tick labels on your plot? Or that you see tick labels, but 'strings 'is an array of empty strings? I can understand that we might have different configurations and the code works for you, but I'd be confused if the elements of 'strings' were all empty.

Comment: [This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dUZa.png) I get. All empty strings for the printed ticklabels, but of course the correct plot. As said, all of this is expected.

Comment: Yes, your output is definitely what I'd expect (and not what I'm seeing). It's helpful to know that it's not an issue for you, which means it's probably not a bug in matplotlib itself. Or maybe it's because I'm on an older version. I'll upgrade my matplotlib and see if it goes away.

Comment: That is _super_ weird.  Please file a bug report if updating does not fix it.